# Subgroup of finitely-generated subgroup

Tags: group-theory, terminology, finitely-generated

Is there a standard name for this concept: Let $H \leq G$ be groups. Say $H$ is ?? if there is a finitely-generated group $K \leq G$ such that $H \leq K$. What should one use in place of "??"? I'm also interested in this notion up to isomorphism.

I've used "finitely subgenerated", though I have realized that "finitely supergenerated" probably makes a bit more sense. If you know a reference/situation where such a thing plays a key role, that may also be useful even if no name is given.

Comment: If $H$ were also finitely-generated, then “finitely subgenerated” would mesh well with current similar terms, like “subnormal.” You might want to take a tour through groupprops to see if you can find any terms that handle a similar condition, but I wasn’t able to.

Answer (score 4):

I'm quite unaware of any such terminology.

As a point of comparison, there is even an important theorem called [Higman's Embedding Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%27s_embedding_theorem) which characterizes, up to isomorphism, those groups which are isomorphic to subgroups of finitely presented groups. Such groups *do* have a special terminology, but that terminology arises not from their embeddability into a finitely presented group but instead from the other side of the characterization in Higman's theorem --- they are precisely the *recursively presented groups*.

So I suggest that if you have a need for such terminology, you judiciously choose it for yourself.